# Is it possible to see .htaccess file of any website?

Tags: .htaccess

Ex. I open http://www.delfi.lt via browser, can I somehow access/open/download .htaccess file of this site?

I read that .htaccess is visable to any browser if it's not hidden by apache. Does apache block access to .htaccess file by default?

Comment: You also could learn some .htaccess via a [cheatsheet](http://addls.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet-v2.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access to .htaccess is disabled by Apache config similar to this in `httpd.conf`:

```
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```